# XSS when displaying json to users

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, xss

I am getting some data in JSON format via jQuery and then I need to display it to users, however it is vulnerable to XSS attack. What are my options here, should I strip chars before I put the data in database? Framework that I am using (Kohana) has a nifty function `HTML::Chars();`, but since I am displaying data with javascript I can't use it there.

One option seems to be is to walk through **every** array element that is being json encoded and apply `HTML::Chars();` to it. Is it the only option, and if so than what would be optimal way of doing this?

Example:

1. User enters some data: `title, body`
2. Data is stored into database
3. Then some other user enters site, data array is taken from database
   and exported to json format
4. My jQuery script is taking the json and appending new element to
   body of my page.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/timeline/latest/1',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                switch (val.type){
                    case 'post': // I have only made post so far
                        addPost(val);
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
function addPost(val){
    $('.content .timeline').prepend(val.title + '<br />' + val.body); // xss vulnerable
}
```

Getting data from database

```
<?php

class Controller_Timeline extends Controller{
    public function Action_Latest(){
        $parentID = $this->request->param('id');
        $modelTimeline = new Model_Timeline();

        // Here I get latest entries, big array
        $latest = $modelTimeline->Latest($parentID);

        // Response it and encode with JSON
        $this->response->body(json_encode($latest));
    }
}
```

My solution so far is this, before I echo out the $latest I walk through array and apply the anti-xss function, I don't know how optimal it is however:

```
array_walk($latest, function(&$latest){
    foreach ($latest as &$key){
        $key = HTML::chars($key);
    }
});
```

Comment: How is that vulnerable to an XSS attack?

Comment: If I type javascript it executes it. Example: I type this into body field `<script type="text/javascript>alert('xss');</script>` and it  will give me alert on the page.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, let me write you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do it like Drupal.

Drupal doesn't filter any input. It stores the text in the database with XSS vulnerabilities if this HTML code were to be displayed without being filtered.

Instead, it filters on the output. You should definitely do that on the server side.

You should inspire yourself from the [`filter_xss()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/filter_xss/8) function Drupal uses.

Make sure it's applied for each of your entry. Do it globally if you can of course, like the following:

```
// In the Model_Timeline class
public function Latest( $id ) {

    // Get your array, and then
    foreach ( $array as $entry ) {

        // Filter each entry
        // I use $util->filter_xss but use it how you implemented it
        $entry = $util->filter_xss( $entry );
    }

    // And return the filtered array
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call mysql_real_escape_string before storing it in the database, htmlspecialchars is optional. Your issue is that you don't want to just display the html to the user, so htmlspecialchars won't work as it encodes things like `<a>` to `&lt;a&gt;` so it isn't suitable if you plan to use the html on the users page (you would have to turn it back into usable html again so it would be redundant).

In this case there is no easy answer - it depends what kind of html you are dealing with? If it is purely presentational like `<em>` `<p>` `<strong>` you should strictly parse the html server side and check it only has these things, and reject or remove any dangerous things like `<script>`. It is more complex though because you would also have to be weary of javascript in element attributes like onClick="do something bad".

In summary, sanitise your html before sending the JSON with PHP, this has the best rep: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: No need for `mysql_real_escape_string();` since it will protect against SQLInjection, since I'm using NoSQL it is impossible to perform sql injection on my website.